# jqtouch - enable Checkbox with Javascript after the user has changed the value

Tags: javascript, html, jqtouch

I use jqtouch and have a checkbox:

```
<li>Checkbox1<span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="Javascript:SetGPIO('1')"> </span></li>
```

I can enable this checkbox:

```
$('#1').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('#1').attr('checked', true);
```

and i can disable

```
$('#1').removeAttr("checked");
```

This works well. 
However, once the user has switched the checkbox, the checkbox can not set by the code above.
I have also tried with:

```
$('#1').prop("checked",false); //Enables the checkbox (?)
$('#1').attr('checked', false); //enables the checkbox (?)
```

What can i do, to set the checkbox via JavaScript, after the user has pressed the checkbox?

[Edit]
I have here a complete example for jqtouch:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>jQTouch &beta;</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/css/jqtouch.css"
    title="jQTouch">

<script src="../../src/lib/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../../src/jqtouch.min.js" type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- Uncomment the following two lines (and comment out the previous two) to use         jQuery instead of Zepto. -->
<!-- <script src="../../src/lib/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="application/x-javascript"     charset="utf-8"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="../../src/jqtouch-jquery.min.js" type="application/x-javascript"         charset="utf-8"></script> -->

<script src="../../extensions/jqt.themeswitcher.min.js"    
type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
        icon : 'jqtouch.png',
        icon4 : 'jqtouch4.png',
        addGlossToIcon : false,
        startupScreen : 'jqt_startup.png',
        statusBar : 'black-translucent',
        themeSelectionSelector : '#jqt #themes ul',
        preloadImages : []
    });

    // Some sample Javascript functions:
    $(function() {

        // Show a swipe event on swipe test
        $('#swipeme').swipe(
                function(evt, data) {
                    var details = !data ? '' : '<strong>' + data    .direction    
                            + '/' + data.deltaX + ':' + data.deltaY    
                            + '</strong>!';
                    $(this).html('You swiped ' + details);
                    $(this).parent().after('<li>swiped!</li>')
                });

        $('#tapme').tap(function() {
            $(this).parent().after('<li>tapped!</li>')
        });

        $('a[target="_blank"]').bind('click', function() {
            if (confirm('This link opens in a new window.')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Page animation callback events
        $('#pageevents').bind(
                'pageAnimationStart',
                function(e, info) {
                    $(this).find('.info').append(
                        'Started animating ' + info.direction    
                                    + '&hellip;  And the link '    
                                    + 'had this custom data: '    
                                    +         $(this).data('referrer').data('custom')
                                    + '<br>'); 
                }).bind(
                'pageAnimationEnd',
                function(e, info) {
                    $(this).find('.info').append(
                            'Finished animating ' + info.direction
                                    + '.<br><br>');

                });

        // Page animations end with AJAX callback event, example 1 (load remote     HTML only first time)
        $('#callback').bind(
                'pageAnimationEnd',
                function(e, info) {
                    // Make sure the data hasn't already been loaded     (we'll set 'loaded' to true a couple lines further down)
                    if (!$(this).data('loaded')) {
                        // Append a placeholder in case the remote     HTML takes its sweet time making it back
                        // Then, overwrite the "Loading"     placeholder text with the remote HTML
                        $(this).append(
                                    $('<div>Loading</div>').load(
                                        'ajax.html .info',    
                                        function() {    
                                            //     Set the 'loaded' var to true so we know not to reload
                                            //     the HTML next time the #callback div animation ends
                                                $(this).parent().data('loaded',
                                                    true);
                                    }));    
                }    
            });    
        // Orientation callback event
        $('#jqt').bind('turn', function(e, data) {
        $('#orient').html('Orientation: ' + data.orientation);
    });

});



function toggleCheckbox(){

if ($('#myCheckbox1').attr('checked') == 'true'){
    $('#myCheckbox1').removeAttr("checked");
}
else {
    $('#myCheckbox1').attr('checked', true);
}
window.setTimeout('toggleCheckbox()', 2000); //toggle every 2 seconds
}

toggleCheckbox();

</script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#jqt.fullscreen #home .info {
display: none;
}

div#jqt #about {
padding: 100px 10px 40px;
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px -1px 0;
color: #999;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
background: #161618;
}

div#jqt #about p {
margin-bottom: 8px;
}

div#jqt #about a {
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jqt">
    <div id="home" class="current">
        <div class="scroll">
            <ul class="rounded">
                <li>MyCheckbox<span class="toggle"><input
                        type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox1" >
                </span>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

The checkbox toggle every 2 seconds, but only until the user clicks on this.

I hope now my question is a little clearer. And sorry for my bad english.
[/edit]

Comment: Can you include a JSFiddle? I don't know what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you're actually doing is checking and unchecking the boxes as opposed to enabling and disabling them (disabled means the user can't check or uncheck the box anymore). Second, the checked property isn't set to true/false (though that would make more sense) you have to set checked to "checked" to have it checked and remove the property to uncheck it.

```
$('#1').attr('checked', 'checked'); //Check
$('#1').removeAttr("checked"); //Uncheck
```